# find User in a list of servers PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a list of servers where I have to find a specific user 'adtuser', and if it is part of the admin group in each server, and output a text file.

For the moment I have this script and it partially works.
I have the desired output, but some server are missing (they are ok if you check individually) and the script require a lot of time.

Thanks in advance

```
Get-Content C:\servers.txt | ForEach-Object {
    if (-not (Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Count 1 -Quiet)) {
        Write-Warning "Server '$_' is Unreachable hence Could not fetch data"
        return
    }
    
    $computer = $_
    ([adsi]"WinNT://$_").Children.ForEach{ 
        if($_.SchemaClassName -ne 'user' -and $_.Name.Value -ne 'ADTuser') {
            return
        }
        
        $groups = $_.Groups().ForEach([adsi]).Name
        
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Computername = $computer
            UserName     = $_.Name.Value
            Memberof     = $groups -join ';'
            Status       = $groups -contains 'Administrators'
        }
    }
} | Out-File -FilePath C:\users.txt
```

Comment: Are you looking for a **local** user? Why not user [Get-LocalUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/get-localuser) then?

Comment: yes is a local user on each server. how did you suggest to  modify the code if I may?

Comment: your `-count 1` is probably missing some on the first attempt.

Comment: most likely you are correct I tried  without with some improvement but still, the script performance is really poor

Comment: I think I already explained in previous question that icmp is not a valid test for this script, you need to test for RPC and SMB (not sure about this one)

Comment: What version of PowerShell can be used on the servers? (AFAIK Get-LocalUser and Get-LocalGroupMembership need version => 5.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be advised that `test-netconnection` requires powerhshell 2.0 or better. Method `.ForEach` requires Powershell 4.0 or better.

As [@Santiago](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) mentioned — I’m using `Test-Connection` with `-port 3389` to test against the Windows RDP port. OP was originally just testing for ICMP connectivity which is a poor test because of common firewall rules.

You could test any know Windows port but RDP is usually pretty safe to assume is open. NMAP (or you network admin …grin) could probably give you the best guidance.

```
#!/usr/bin/env powershell
Get-Content -Path $env:HOMEDRIVE/servers.txt | ForEach-Object {
if (-not (Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Count 1 -Quiet)) {
    Write-Warning -Message ("Server '{0}' is Unreachable hence Could not fetch data" -f $_)
    return
}

$computer = $_
([adsi]('WinNT://{0}' -f $_)).Children.ForEach{ 
    if($_.SchemaClassName -ne 'user' -and $_.Name.Value -ne 'ADTuser') {
        return
    }
    
$groups = $_.Groups().ForEach([adsi]).Name
    
[pscustomobject]@{
        Computername = $computer
        UserName     = $_.Name.Value
        Memberof     = $groups -join ';'
        Status       = $groups -contains 'Administrators'
  }
 }
} | Out-File -FilePath $env:HOMEDRIVE/users.txt
```

Comment: In a `foreach ($thing in $collectionOfThings)` loop, you cannot use the `$_` automatic variable. Also, I would output the results in a structured CSV file using `Export-Csv` instead of writing out **objects** with `Out-File` (which is meant to write **strings**)

Comment: thanks for removing the test-net connection the script is way faster but now I need to format my txt file in this kind of format LHRBHSPING|26.04.22 12:15|AccessSwitchCheck|NONE|OK| how can I do that by having the text in one line at the end I need a .DAT file to use it in a software

Comment: It would be nice to have an explanation as to why testing RDP connectivity is relevant for this script. I think this answer is missguiding

Comment: @ElyasKarim you’d have to create new fields for the CSV based on the responses to the test and the output that data in the format you want.

Comment: ... But what does a series of `Write-Host` lines have to do with writing **objects** to a file?. Using `Out-File` is **not** meant for that. Use `Export-Csv`

Comment: @Theo you were correct. i fixed the `$_` reference.

Comment: I'm not sure what your intent is `Foreach-Object [adsi].Name`, this is not a valid syntax. Also inside your `ForEach-Object` you're referring to `$item` when you should be referring to `$_`. If you don't understand the code, my sincere advise would be to leave as I originally posted it changing only the `Test-NetConnection` line

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked, if your servers can all use PowerShell version 5.1 or higher, you can make use of the `Get-Local*` cmdlets.

From your question, you are specifically looking for a certain user `ADTuser`

```
$userToCheck = 'ADTuser'
$servers     = Get-Content -Path 'C:\servers.txt'
$cred        = Get-Credential -Message 'Please enter your admin credentials'

# loop through the list of servers and collect the output objects
$result = foreach ($computer in $servers) {
    if (-not (Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -Quiet)) {
        Write-Warning -Message "Server '$computer' is Unreachable hence Could not fetch data"
        # output a failed object
        '' | Select-Object @{Name = 'ComputerName'; Expression = {$computer}}, UserName,MemberOf, 
                           @{Name = 'Status'; Expression = {'Unreachable'}}
        # skip processing this server and proceed with the next one
        continue
    }
    # here we probe the server for the existance of user $userToCheck
    $out = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
        $user = Get-LocalUser -Name $using:userToCheck -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        if ($user) {
            # get the names of all local groups the user is member of
            $userGroups = (Get-LocalGroup | Where-Object { ($_ | Get-LocalGroupMember).SID -contains $user.SID }).Name
            [PsCustomObject]@{
                Computername = $env:COMPUTERNAME
                UserName     = $user.Name
                MemberOf     = $userGroups -join '; '
                Status       = $userGroups -contains 'Administrators'
            }
        }
        else {
            [PsCustomObject]@{
                Computername = $env:COMPUTERNAME
                UserName     = $using:userToCheck
                MemberOf     = $null
                Status       = "User does not exist"
            }                
        }
    }
    # output the object but remove extra properties PowerShell added
    $out | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty PS*, RunspaceId
}

# show in the console window
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# you can now use Export-Csv to output the results in a structured file you can open with Excel
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\users.csv' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```